# How to encode a string into an existing byte buffer without allocating a new array each time?

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have this simple code:

```
class Thing {
 public string Message{get; set;}
 public byte[] GetBytes() => Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Message);
```

In my case I want to add these bytes into a larger, pre-allocated buffer. I can't see any way to implement`GetBytes` to avoid allocating an array each time since `Encoding.GetBytes` is quite limited, am I missing something? If I am dealing with a lot of `Thing` instances then I just have to accept this performance hit?

I had preferred to be able to write something like `GetBytes(byte []buffer)` or even better `GetBytes(ArraySegment<byte> buffer)`

Comment: In .NET Core 2.1+, `Encoding.GetBytes` has [a `Span`-based overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netcore-2.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_Span_System_Byte__). Unfortunately most of the newer work on `Span`-optimized methods is not going to be backported to .NET Framework. There are still overloads taking arrays with offsets and lengths, though.

Comment: Sadly I'm not sure we're ready to transition to Core yet, as far as I know all our codebase is Framework.

Comment: Note, `Encoding.Default` is bad juju: on .NET Framework it's your operation system's default encoding (which could literally be *anything*). On .NET Core they fixed that so it's UTF-8. It's highly recommended that you *don't* use it unless you're in the incredibly rare position of actually needing it

Comment: Without using Span, it's only possible using unsafe code.

Comment: @canton7 thanks that must've come from some sample code. Luckily this is just being used for testing but I will remember for the future

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Except... [it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netcore-2.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_)?

Comment: @canton7 thats great, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overload [`int GetBytes (string s, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netcore-2.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_):

```
public int GetBytes(byte[] array) =>
    encoding.GetBytes(Message, 0, Message.Length, array, 0);
```

Or:

```
public int GetBytes(ArraySegment<byte> segment) =>
    encoding.GetBytes(Message, 0, Message.Length, segment.Array, segment.Offset);
```

Note that there's no checking whether you've exceeded the portion of the array described by the `ArraySegment`: if you've got an `ArraySegment` which ends before the underlying array, this will happily write up to the end of the array. You might want to add a check, using the return value of `encoding.GetBytes`.

Alternatively, if you're using .NET Core 2.1 or higher, you've got access to [`int GetBytes (ReadOnlySpan<char> chars, Span<byte> bytes)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netcore-2.1#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_Span_System_Byte__) (allowing you to use a `Span<byte>` instead of an `ArraySegment<byte>`):

```
public int GetBytes(Span<byte> span) =>
    encoding.GetBytes(Message, span);
```

Comment: `string` can be directly passed to the first `char[]` param?

Comment: @Mr.Boy If this answered your question, please consider accepting it